# About the relationship between Cayley-Chow families and well-defined family of proper cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

I'm studying Chow varieties introduced in Chapter I.3-4 of "Rational curves on algebraic varieties" [Kol96] by János Kollár and also very interested in the "open" Chow variety described in (3.7.1) of "[Families of varieties of general type](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ekollar/FromMyHomePage/modbook-final.pdf)" [Kol23]. I would like to ask about the relationship between the Cayley-Chow family [Kol23, Definition 3.5] and the well-defined family of proper cycles [Kol96, I.3.11]. I guess that Cayley-Chow family is a synonym of "well-defined family of geometrically reduced proper cycles which satisfies the field of definition condition", but only can understand that an object of the former is naturally an object of the latter.

The specific setting of my question is as follows. All schemes are noetherian. Let $S$ be a reduced (or seminormal if it helps) base scheme and let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}_{S}^{N}$ be a reduced closed subscheme which satisfies the following properties:

(i) The structure morphism $X\rightarrow S$ is of pure relative dimension $n$ in the sense of [Kol23, 2.71], i.e. $X_T$ is of pure dimension $n+\text{dim}(T)$ for every integral scheme $T$ over $S$.

(ii) For every $s\in S$, the $n$-cycle $[X_{s,\text{red}}]$ on $X_s$ is geometrically reduced and satisfies the following property. Let $T\rightarrow S$ be a morphism from the spectrum of a DVR to $S$ which maps the generic point of $T$ to a generic point of $S$ and maps the special point of $T$ to $s$, and let $\{X_i\}$ be all of the irreducible components of $X$. Then $[X_{s,\text{red}}]$ and $\sum\limits_{i}[(\text{pure}(X_{i,T}))_0]_n$ are essentially the same $n$-cycles on $X_s$. The cycle is obtained by "taking the associated $n$-cycle of the special fiber of the scheme-theoretic closure of the generic fiber of $X_{i,T}$" and essentially the same means same after base field extension.

**Question:** For every  $s\in S$, does $X_s$ necessarily be generically reduced?

I wonder that whether the operation $\text{pure}$ can make the components of the special fiber thinner.

My motivation is towards [Kol23, 3.7.1]. It seems that it is deduced by [Kol96, I.4.14], but using this (4.14) I can only find an appropriate open Chow variety which parametrizes "well-defined family of geometrically reduced proper cycles which satisfies the field of definition condition" (maybe I made some mistakes). So I guess this kind of family of cycles should coincide with the Cayley-Chow families.

**Edit:** I find a seemingly relative statement in David Rydh's [thesis](https://people.kth.se/%7Edary/thesis/thesis.pdf). In [page 5, (B9)] of the paper "Families of cycles", the author says that "multiplicity-free relative cycles correspond to subschemes which
are flat with reduced fibers over an open fiberwise dense subset". I hope that "multiplicity-free" is somehow equivalent to "has geometrically reduced cycle theoretic fibers". If so, then we are done. But since Rydh's articles introduced many original concepts and are a bit difficult for me as a beginner in algebraic geometry, I'm still looking forward to a more direct answer to my question. Thank you!